# Whether to use "as" or "to" after the phrase "a similar, if not the same"

Tags: grammar

> *X* has a similar, if not the same, function **as** *Y*.
>
> {or}: *X* has a similar, if not the same, function **to** *Y*.

I'm leaning towards using "as", since the word "same" is placed closer. Then again, if you consider the phrase "if not the same" to be of secondary importance, the word "similar" may well be the one given precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to write is:

- X has a function similar to, if not the same as, Y's (function).

or

- X has a similar function to, if not the same (function) as, Y.

or

- X and Y have similar, if not the same, functions.